# how to populate specific cells from a multi column list box - excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list box (`lbxStN`) with 3 columns (`0-fmMultiSelectSingle`).
I would like to make a selection (only one) in this list, and have the data from each column of the list shown in a specific cell in a specific sheet (sheet: `DeN`). First column from the list `F19`, second column `C22` and third column `H22`. After button (`cmdBtnSelect2`) is clicked.
Data for the list box is stored in a different sheet in the same workbook.

```
Private Sub cmdBtnSelect2_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim myVar4 As String
Dim myVar5 As String
Dim myVar6 As String

For i = 0 To lbxStN.ListCount - 1

    If lbxStN.Selected(i) = True Then

        lbxStN.List(i, 0).Value = myVar4
        lbxStN.List(i, 1).Value = myVar5
        lbxStN.List(i, 2).Value = myVar6
    End If

Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("F19") = myVar4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("C22") = myVar5
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("H22") = myVar6

End Sub
```

If I run the code, I get a  `'424' Object required` error.
 
Which means I'm missing something basic.?

Comment: When you tested the code, did you select an option from the listbox? There's no default listed, so if no option is selected how will Excel know the value?

Comment: Your assignment is backwards. `myVar4 = lbxStN.List(i, 0).Value` otherwise you are assigning an empty object to the listbox, which will causes an error.

Comment: what do you mean with "default listed"
i can select from a list

when "message box" was added (as a test) it listed/displayed the selection
but only the first column

Comment: "default" means that to give a variable an initial value, or a value if no value is selected. Without this, if a user clicks the button without selecting an option, an error will be thrown as there is nothing to assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you intend to do, there is no need to create new variables. The value from the selected item can be assigned directly to the cells. As follows

```
Private Sub cmdBtnSelect2_Click()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 0 To lbxStN.ListCount - 1
        If lbxStN.Selected(i) Then
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("F19") = lbxStN.List(i, 0)
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("C22") = lbxStN.List(i, 1)
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeN").Range("H22") = lbxStN.List(i, 2)

          Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The previous subroutine iterates for each iteam in the list, and checks if the item is selected. If the item is selected, then it assigns each column to each cell. `Exit For` will exit the iteration, because there is no need to continue looking for more selected items.

I tested the code with the following subroutine to add items to the list. I think it would be a good idea to compare it with yours in case you have tried to do a complex assignment.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    lbxStN.Clear

    lbxStN.AddItem "a"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 1) = "a2"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 2) = "a3"

    lbxStN.AddItem "b"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 1) = "b2"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 2) = "b3"

    lbxStN.AddItem "c"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 1) = "c2"
    lbxStN.List(lbxStN.ListCount - 1, 2) = "c3"
End Sub
```

I usually get better at coding by reading someone elses code and trying to understand it

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Dr Yunke, it works :D

I do try and understand other peoples codes. But I got bogged down with this particular part of my project.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer